# Jupyter Notebook Dead Kernel after reinstalling pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I had to reset my Windows 10 PC, reinstall python, jupyter and Pycharm, but kept my notebooks. When I run the jupyter server, it shows the notebook but the kernel is dead and the console shows the following error. How can I make the kernel work?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file
    kernel_name=self.kernel_name
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "C:\Users\DianaCarolina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 100, in secure_write
    win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
  File "c:\users\dianacarolina\google drive\clases\particulares\venv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 58, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
    admins, _domain, _type = win32security.LookupAccountName("", "Administrators")
pywintypes.error: (1332, 'LookupAccountName', 'No se efectuó ninguna asignación entre los nombres de cuenta y los identificadores de seguridad.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had installed python for 32 bits so I installed the 64-bit python and now it works.